# Any way to show url-info with $router.push()?

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

Recently I've replaced all `router-link` anchor elements in my app with `$router.push()` directives. Now I've noticed, that `$router.push()` hides the `url-info` in the bottom of the viewport and prevents the user from opening new tabs with `CTRL/CMD + click`.

Is there any way to show the `url-info` on hover and enable the creation of new browser tabs with the above shortcut?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you replace all `<router-link>` with `$router.push()`? What element is the `$router.push()` attached to?

Comment: @tony19 Because I'm a noob and found adding the `$router.push()` / `$router.back()` statements to an element simpler than having to put `<router-link>` tags around elements. But I get from you that this appears to be bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Add a keypress event to the document body (or other parent div) to handle the navigation.

Set the title attribute of your link-like element to the target URL.